# Яке має значення слово "кайстроник"?

Tags: значення-слів

[Варила мамочка кашичку](https://uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D1%83,_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0)

> Варила мамочка кашичку, варила.
> Одному дала до горнятка,
> Другому до мисочки,
> Третьому до ***кайстроника***,
> Четвертому дала до ложки,
> А п’ятому не дала,
> Бо не приніс сала.

Яке значення слова "кайстроник"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Кайстроник** - глиняний горщик-каструля у південних лемків. Найближче споріднене зі словом *каструля*, що є запозичене з французької мови за російським і німецьким посередництвом.

> ...**Кайстроник** – є характерним найменуванням глиняної «каструлі» у
>   південних лемків. Також зазначається причина, чому мама не дала каші
>   п'ятій дитині – «бо не приніс сала». З цього випливає, що й іншим
>   своїм дітям, вона розділяла кашу, зважаючи на виконану ними роботу.
>   Відповідно до цього, мати насипала кашу в посудини, які мають різну
>   місткість, що й визначало, хто працював більше й краще всіх:
>
> *«Варила мамочка кашичку, варила.
>
>   Єдному дала до горнятка,
>
>   Другому до мисочки,
>
>   Третьому до кайстроника,
>
>   Четвертому дала до ложки,
>
>   А п’ятому не дала,
>
>   Бо не приніс сала»*

Позичено [звідси](http://philology.knu.ua/files/library/lit_st/40-2/22.pdf) і [звідси](http://bo0k.net/index.php?p=chapter&bid=1433&chapter=1).

Виглядає [отак](https://www.facebook.com/1557760981205330/photos/a.1558076394507122/1592611924386902/?type=3&theater):

[image]

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Дякуємо, що приєдналися до спільноти.

Comment: @P.Vovk Дуже дякую : ]

Comment: А, і ще сподіваємось на плідну співпрацю! Ледь не забув))